# Canceling a Firebase Storage UploadTask triggers error

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to upload a zip file to Firebase Storage but I also want to be able to "Cancel" this upload, so I created a Static UploadTask (ValueNotifier) variable like this:

```
SettingsUtils.uploadStatus.value = ref.putFile(targetZipFile);
```

But, when I try to invoke the method cancel ( `SettingsUtils.uploadStatus.value.cancel()` ), this gives me the following exception :

[image]

I'm doing something wrong? How can I treat this exception properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the default behavior, see here:

> In addition to starting uploads, you can pause, resume, and cancel
> uploads using the pause(), resume(), and cancel() methods. Pause and
> resume events raise pause and progress state changes respectively.
> Canceling an upload causes the upload to fail with an error indicating
> that the upload was canceled.

Wrap it inside a try catch and check if the code is "canceled". If yes, it worked.

What i also found, you can listen to differen states like this:

```
uploadTask.snapshotEvents.listen((TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
  switch (taskSnapshot.state) {
    case TaskState.running:
      final progress =
          100.0 * (taskSnapshot.bytesTransferred / taskSnapshot.totalBytes);
      print("Upload is $progress% complete.");
      break;
    case TaskState.paused:
      print("Upload is paused.");
      break;
    case TaskState.canceled:
      print("Upload was canceled");
      break;
    case TaskState.error:
      // Handle unsuccessful uploads
      break;
    case TaskState.success:
      // Handle successful uploads on complete
      // ...
      break;
  }
```

From the official docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/flutter/upload-files

Comment: With my previous code, I was getting confused with the error handling, but your answer enlightened me. The problem is that I wasn't dealing with the exception on canceling the task properly and the exception was breaking the code. With properly treatment, the code is running fine now! Thanks a lot @targiasld